# Writing a local file from an external FTP server - Issue with Varien_Io_File

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, ftp, varien-io-file

I have a script that pulls a file from an external server, and tries to save it locally (to then be processed).  I'm using Varien_Io_Ftp() to facilitate this, however, upon saving the file locally, it throws the following exception, despite creating the file that is required which upsets me.

```
Warning: chdir(): Invalid argument (errno 22)  in C:\wamp\www\xxxxx\shop\lib\Varien\Io\File.php on line 547
```

This line in Varien_Io_File is the only one in the vacinity that doesn't have error suppression added to it.  Is this a bug, or should I be setting _iwd somewhere within my call?

Hopefully some code to explain the call below:

```
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'var' . DS . 'import' . DS . 'stock' . DS;
$localFile = $importDir . "StockUpdate_" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".csv";

$file = new Varien_Io_File();
$file->mkdir($importDir);
$pickupFile = new Varien_Io_Ftp();

try {
    $pickupFile->open(
        array(
            'host'      => $host,
            'user'      => $username,
            'password'  => $password,
            'timeout'   => '10'
        )
    );

    $pickupFile->cd($remoteDir);
    $_fileToImportRemoteTmp = $pickupFile->read($remoteFile);
    $pickupFile->close();

    if (!$file->write($localFile, $_fileToImportRemoteTmp)) {
        die("cannot write local file :/");
    }
    $file->close();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

The exception I being thrown with this line:

```
if (!$file->write($localFile, $_fileToImportRemoteTmp)) {
```

Comment: I dont think you manually need to save the file using $file see second option of  string "read" method (string $filename, [string|resource|null $dest = null]) .. "string|resource|null $dest: destination file name, stream, or if null will return file contents". See http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Io/Varien_Io_Ftp.html#read

Comment: Added to the question :)

Comment: Shouldn't '$localFile' be "/path/too/file.csv" instead of  "file.csv"

Comment: I use $file->cd() prior to the "write" line.  If I combine the dir & filename, and drop the call to cd(), unfortunatley I get the same error anyway.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $localFile` and `echo  $_fileToImportRemoteTmp`

Comment: $localFile is "StockUpdate_2014-11-05-16-30-01.csv" and $_fileToImportRemoteTmp contains the file contents.  As decribed in the question, the function works exactly how I want (and creates the file and populates it), but throws an exception anyway.

Comment: Change `$localFile = Mage::getBaseDir() . '/StockUpdate_' . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.csv'`;

Comment: File is created in root, but exception is still thrown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18423/discussion-between-douglas-radburn-and-r-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking at this in the future, RS has provided an example that works, but I wanted to jump in and give a little explanation about WHY his solution works.

The exception being thrown at lib\Varien\Io\File.php on line 547 is due to the reference to `$this->_iwd` not being supressed (and inherently, the fact that it isn't set).  I'm assuming this *isn't* a bug, despite the fact tht you can clearly call the function directly. I'm guessing that the intention is that you call the `->open()` function prior to making any action upon a file.

The `open()` function sets a reference to `_iwd` (if you pass a `path` into it to begin with). i.e.

```
$file->open(array('path' => $importDir));
```

Grabbing a reference to Varien_Io_File, and making a direct call to `cd`, whilst possible, doesn't follow the correct flow, therefore when you `write`, the original reference to `_iwd` isn't in place.

It's worth pointing out that you need to call:

```
$file->mkdir($importDir);
```

prior to calling `open()`.

Additionally, RS noted that http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-code-library/ has an example, however, the inital code doesn't mention the limitation above and actually calls `->write()` directly too.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'var' . DS . 'import' . DS . 'stock' . DS;
$localFile = $importDir . "StockUpdate_" . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".csv";

$file = new Varien_Io_File();
$file->open(array('path' => $importDir)); 
$file->mkdir($importDir);

$pickupFile = new Varien_Io_Ftp();

try {
    $pickupFile->open(
        array(
            'host'      => $host,
            'user'      => $username,
            'password'  => $password,
            'timeout'   => '10'
        )
    );

    $pickupFile->cd($remoteDir);
    $_fileToImportRemoteTmp = $pickupFile->read($remoteFile);
    $pickupFile->close();

    if (!$file->write($localFile, $_fileToImportRemoteTmp)) {
        die("cannot write local file :/");
    }
    $file->close();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Hi RS - can you expand your answer to clarify why this works (and it does - I came to the same conclusion), and I'll accept it as the answer. Otherwise, I'll put together an answer.

Comment: Cheers RS.  I'll happily add an answer.  Just wanted something expanded for anyone coming across this in the future :) - no point accepting this and not pointing out WHY it works in my mind.

Comment: Good luck next time, if you feel like it need explanation you could alway add a comment, but 2hrs wasted for no reason

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$pickupFile = new Varien_Io_Ftp();

$localDir = "/path/to/local/dir";
$remoteFile = "/path/to/remote/dir/text.csv"

mkdir($localDir, 0700, true);


$localFile = $localDir . '/local.csv'
try {
    $pickupFile->open(
        array(
            'host'      => $host,
            'user'      => $username,
            'password'  => $password,
            'timeout'   => '10'
        )
    );

    $pickupFile->read($remoteFile, $localFile);


} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

See [Varien_Io_Ftp](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Io/Varien_Io_Ftp.html#read)

Also for security you way want to use [Varien_Io_Sftp](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Io/Varien_Io_Sftp.html)

Comment: It seems like in the limited scope of my example, that this would work (with Varien_Io_Ftp) - however, if I need to manipulate the content before it's saved, I wouldn't be able to.  My question remains - is this a bug in Varien_Io_File?

Comment: It's may be wise to manipulate file locally